# Как инвертировать цвет текста обводки в зависимости от фона

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

У меня есть два `div` шириной 50% каждый. Существует огромный заголовок `h1`, который должен иметь цвет этих двух элементов `div`. Я пробовал `mix-blend-mode`, но он дает мне несколько случайных цветов при настройке на разницу.

Моя цель - инвертировать цвета, но сохранить цвета `div`. Это файл `codepen`, я постарался сделать его максимально простым:
   https://codepen.io/lukagurovic/pen/MLoZmj

Окончательный эффект должен выглядеть следующим образом:

http://jsfiddle.net/1uubdtz6/

Но я не знаю, почему это не работает с этими цветами. Кроме того, эти элементы `div` являются интерактивными, поэтому цвет должен динамически изменяться, так как элементы `div` увеличиваются в ширине при наведении, и должно быть только обводка текста без заливки.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54517767/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одной из идей является дублирование текста и использование переменной `CSS` для определения цвета, чтобы вы могли легко изменить их в одном месте. Я использовал `clip-path`, чтобы скрыть половину одного текста и показать другую:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  --c1:#510035;
  --c2:#E8E8E8;
}
body:hover {
  --c1:#E8E8E8;
  --c2:crimson;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}
.first {
  background:var(--c1);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px var(--c2);
}

.second {
  background:var(--c2);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px var(--c1);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%,0% 100%);
}

.lp-header {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  min-height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="lp-header first">left or right</h1>
<h1 class="lp-header second">left or right</h1>
```

Comment: Интересная штука, я бы добавил плавности перехода, а то как-то резко. Ну тут главное показан принцип работы такого эффекта. Такой эффект классно применять в рекламных предложениях. Спасибо!